# WPF Datagrid row foreground color multitrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-style

I want to change foreground color of a datagrid when mouse is over and row is selected at the same time.

My code is following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#d2c09e"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It changes color only for one cell.

But this works:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
```

It doesn't work when I want to change color when mouse is over.

So how can I do that?

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The **MultiTrigger** applies the associated setters or actions when all of the conditions are **true(binary AND operation)**. So, in your case only when both IsSelected and IsMouseOver is satisfied, the foreground is changed.

As mentioned, the trigger will fire on all the conditions being AND'd, which was why it didn't work when you put all the conditions together. The easiest way to produce an OR (without implementing a IMultiValueConverter), is to have multiple datatriggers (which imply a binary OR operation) or triggers separately.

You can use a **Trigger** separately instead of the **MultiTrigger** for the **DataGridCell**.

Check below code. I have tested it and it is working perfectly in my side. Please try and revert if any issues.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I want to set foreground color when those two actions are true.

Comment: Then multitriggers is enough to get your job done.  Then what else is your issue? Do you want to change entire row's foreground color?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.